# datastore get last key in range?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, key

I have a set of objects that I created according to some google docs recommendation for objects you want to have locality.

So I have objects with keys of the form 'Name#00000001'. My thing is I have an operation I need to get the last one of these so I can get them all with the code below.

```
var query = datastore.createQuery('Post')
        .select('__key__')
        .filter('__key__', '>=', datastore.key(['Post', req.query["Thread"] + "#00000001"]))
        .filter('__key__', '<=', datastore.key(['Post', req.query["Thread"] + "#99999999"]));
```

Things is when I do stuff like

```
var query = datastore.createQuery('Post')
        .select('__key__')
        .filter('__key__', '>=', datastore.key(['Post', req.query["Thread"] + "#00000001"]))
        .filter('__key__', '<=', datastore.key(['Post', req.query["Thread"] + "#99999999"]))
        .order('__key__',{descending: true})
        .limit(1);
```

It fails. It seems I can't order by key at all. The items have time stamps in addition to this, but it seems you can't filter by 1 item and order by another. Is there anyway to get the last item with a query without querying everything?

Answer (score 0):

In Google Cloud-Java see StructuredQuery.  You can .setOrderBy(OrderBy.asc("__key__"))

Comment: But datastore supports indexes, in which case it's best to think of the indexed data has a large binary tree. You would expect to be able to get the last element from a binary tree...